# List total N in header of tbl_stack

Tags: r, gtsummary

When I do a tbl_stack, I'd like to show the total N of the combined tables in the tbl_stack in the header. At the moment the result appears to show the N of the first table in the stack.

```
  trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response, trt) %>%
  filter(grade == "I") %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    label = list(age ~ "Patient Age"),
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
    digits = list(age ~ c(0, 1))
  )
tbl_summary_ex2a <-
  trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response, trt) %>%
  filter(grade %in% c("II", "III", "IV")) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    label = list(age ~ "Patient Age"),
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
    digits = list(age ~ c(0, 1))
  )

tbl_stack(tbls=list(tbl_summary_ex2, tbl_summary_ex2a))
```

[image]
Thanks for any tips,
Jeff

Comment: can you show the expected output? If there are different Ns in the table and then combining then do you think that would confuse people ? Can you make one large table and then have Unknowns represent where there is missing data?

Comment: Hmmm, I agree with @Mike, depending on the situation, the Ns printed could be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the documentation of `tbl_stack()` indicates, the headers are retained from the first gtsummary in the stack.  You can use the `modify_header()` function to change the headers, however. Additionally, these gtsummary tables have an internal object, `.$df_by`, that saves the Ns from each of your tables.  You can sum the Ns across tables using these internal data frames.  Example below doing this programmatically, but if it's easier you could simply hard code the Ns.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

tbl_summary_ex2 <-
  trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response, trt) %>%
  filter(grade == "I") %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    label = list(age ~ "Patient Age"),
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
    digits = list(age ~ c(0, 1)),
    include = -grade
  )
tbl_summary_ex2a <-
  trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response, trt) %>%
  filter(grade %in% c("II", "III", "IV")) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    label = list(age ~ "Patient Age"),
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
    digits = list(age ~ c(0, 1)),
    include = -grade
  )

# calculate the sum total Ns from both tables
list_N <- 
  tbl_summary_ex2$df_by %>%
  bind_rows(tbl_summary_ex2a$df_by) %>%
  select(by_col, by, n) %>%
  group_by(by_col, by) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>%
  mutate(
    header_update = 
      str_glue("{by_col} ~ '**{by}**, N = {n}'") %>%
      as.formula() %>%
      list()
  ) %>%
  pull(header_update)
list_N

tbl_stack(
  tbls=list(tbl_summary_ex2, tbl_summary_ex2a),
  group_header = c("Grade I", "Grade > I")
) %>%
  modify_header(list_N)
```

[image]